# Minimum of the maximum values

Tags: sql, t-sql

Consider the below results

```
Datetime1   DateTime2   Customer
2013-06-19  2011-03-30  IP003779    
2014-04-24  2011-03-30  IP003779    
2011-03-30  2009-03-18  IP003779
```

i need to select the minimum of the first column out of the maximums of the second column.
-> 2013-06-19

I'm having a hard time figuring out the query, combining min and max. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do, I think, to find the min of the max for each customer:

```
select Customer        =      t.Customer    ,
       DateTime2_Max   =      t.dt2Max      ,
       DateTime1_Min   = min( x.DateTime1 )
from ( select Customer = Customer ,
              dt2Max   = max( DateTime2 ) 
       from some_table
       group by Customer
     ) t
join some_table x on x.Customer  = t.Customer
                 and x.DateTime2 = t.dt2Max
group by t.Customer ,
         t.dt2Max
```

If you want to look at the table overall, then it gets simpler:

```
select DateTime2_Max =      t.dt2Max      ,
       DateTime1_Min = min( x.DateTime1 )
from ( select dt2Max   = max( DateTime2 ) 
       from some_table
     ) t
join some_table x on x.DateTime2 = t.dt2Max
group by t.dt2Max
```

You could also use windowing functions. Broken out by customer, it looks something like:

```
select *
from ( select * ,
              rank = row_number() over (
                       partition by Customer
                       order by DateTime2 desc ,
                                DateTime1 asc
                       )
     ) t
where t.rank = 1
order by 1,2,3
```

And again, simpler if you look at the table as a whole:

```
select top 1 *
from ( select * ,
              rank = row_number() over (
                       order by DateTime2 desc ,
                                DateTime1 asc
                       )
     ) t
where t.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select top 1 *
from table t
order by DateTime2 desc, DateTime1 asc;
```

Edit:

If you need to do this for all customers, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by datetime2 desc, datetime1 asc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: not quite, if i do top 1, i only get the result from one customer, i need to run this on the whole customer table

Comment: @BelgoCanadian . . . When asking a question, you should strive to include all relevant information.